# How do intake deflectors work?

Tags: turboprop

Some turboprop aircraft, for example [DHC 6 Twin Otter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Canada_DHC-6_Twin_Otter) have “intake deflectors” which should be engaged when taking off from or landing on unpaved surface to prevent foreign object damage. But how does it actually work?

Comment: First hit on Google: http://airplanepilot.blogspot.fi/2005/06/intake-deflectors.html

Comment: @VilleNiemi second hit on google: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16206/how-do-intake-deflectors-work , and that one has illustrations too! ;)

Comment: @falstro I have to say I am impressed by the google fu of the stackexchange. This probably isn't that common a search term, but still...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This [document](https://www.pwc.ca/files/en/Know_your_PT6A.pdf) describes it nicely. They are also known as inertial seperators:

> The nacelle inlet of many aircraft models includes an inertial separator 
>   provided by the aircraft manufacturer to prevent heavy particles from 
>   entering the engine inlet. Most installations incorporate two moveable 
>   vanes, one upstream of the engine inlet and the other blocking the bypass 
>   duct. For bypass operation, the inlet vane is lowered and the bypass 
>   duct vane is opened permitting maximum separating efficiency. In some 
>   installations, the vanes are fixed in the bypass mode.
>
> **As shown in the sketch, air entering the engine inlet must turn sharply past the inlet vane (shown in the lowered position). Particles heavier than air are carried straight through, by their own inertia, into the bypass duct and dumped overboard.**
>
> The aft radial inlet design provides many advantages such as superior 
>   anti-icing utilizing the principle of inertial separation, low noise levels and unequalled protection from FOD.

[image]