# What are these engine inlet devices used for?

Tags: military, turbine, bird-strike, ch-47

While looking at the Boeing Chinook CH-47 for [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44918/3201), I noticed the screens in front of the engines, and found similar devices in other photos:

[image]
<sup>Source: [left](http://www.airliners.net/photo/USA-Army/Boeing-MH-47G-Chinook-414/2281241) -- [right](http://www.worldwide-military.com/Military%20Heli's/US-transport/CH-47_English.htm)</sup>

- What are these devices used for?

A recurrent question here is about protecting turbine engines against bird/FOD ingestion. It seems that a screen can be used, at least at low speed.

- It is the case? Is it used for this purpose?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The first photo shows the engine air intake screen. Its basically a screen to prevent FOD ingestion, as you noted. From [CH-47 Theory of Operations](http://www.chinook-helicopter.com/Publications/Theory_Of_Operation/CH-47_Theory_of_Operations.pdf):

> Engine Inlet Screens
>
> An engine inlet screen which maximizes foreign object damage (FOD) is installed on each engine. The reduction in engine power available with screens installed is negligible. The engine inlet screens have bypass panels.  These two panels are on the aft end of each screen. Quick release fasteners attach the panels to the screens. They are removed if the ambient temperature
> is 4°C or below and there is visible moisture

- I'm pretty sure it is supposed to be *minimizes* foreign object damage.

It is an All Weather Screen (AWS) intended primarily to prevent ingestion of large items that would cause foreign object damage to the compressor blades.

[image: Chinook engine]

By [Mr.Z-man](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Mr.Z-man) - Own work, [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=4668325)

The second photo shows the Engine Air Particle Separator(EAPS) unit, which in this case is the  [Pall PUREair System](https://shop.pall.com/us/en/aerospace/commercial-rotary-wing/engine-air-protection/pall-pureair-system-for-boeing-ch-47-chinook-helicopter-zidgri78lb2)

[image: PUREair]

Pall PUREair system; image from [Pall aerospace](https://shop.pall.com/us/en/aerospace/commercial-rotary-wing/engine-air-protection/pall-pureair-system-for-boeing-ch-47-chinook-helicopter-zidgri78lb2)

The EAPS is there primarily to protect against ingestion of sand and dust, which, according to [Why an Engine Air Particle Separator (EAPS)?](http://proceedings.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/proceeding.aspx?articleid=2208967) can cause multiple problems like,

- erosion of compressor blades
- clogging turbine cooling passages
- cause sulphidation, corrosion and overheating

As the article notes,

> A CH-47 in the desert with only the AWS could achieve only 12 landings before both engines were changed. With EAPS, it did 13 landings with no change in horsepower. in another desert test CH-47 engines with AWS deteriorated to an unacceptable level in only 30 hours. With EAPS, there was no degradation.

In case of desert environments, EAPS is a must if you want your engine to survive any more than double digit hours. This particular type of EAPS belongs to the Vortex tube separators and uses a vortex generator to separate the sand and dust from air.

> Contaminated air entering the ... air cleaner tube assembly is given a swirling motion induced by the vortex generator. This swirling motion causes the heavier dirt particle and water droplets to be thrown radially outward by centrifugal force toward the wall of the tube.

[image: EAPS operation]

Principle of EAPS operation, image from Pall aerospace.

You can find about other types and their operation in [A Comparative Study of Helicopter Engine Particle Separators](https://www.research.manchester.ac.uk/portal/files/20237399/POST-PEER-REVIEW-NON-PUBLISHERS.PDF)

Comment: I suppose you must be right about the typo for the screens :-) Any idea about what prevents their use in turbofan hot flow and fixed wing turbo/jet/prop?

Comment: @mins The operational envelope of helicopters and aircraft are quite different. Simply put, the cost in design, weight, drag, maintenance etc of the screens are not enough to offset their supposed [benefits in FOD ingestion in the normal aircraft operating environment](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14342/9731). Also, note the point about the reduction in engine power due to them.

Comment: @mins I would surmise that the big difference between helicopters and fixed wing in this situation is the speed. You can make a screen that can stand up to bird strikes at helicopter speeds but at fixed wing speed a large bird would penetrate and take the screen with it. They’re also less needed for sand, etc. The debris thrown up by a fixed wing is mostly behind the engine whereas a helicopter is right in the middle of its downwash.

Comment: @mins, turboprops designed for use on unpaved runways, e.g. dhc-6, [do use “intake deflectors”](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16206/how-do-intake-deflectors-work), which is a simpler kind of EAPS. The simpler version is sufficient because in fixed-wing aircraft the engine is not blowing up debris ahead of itself, so less sand and dust gets ingested.

Comment: @mins in a high bypass ratio turbofan, the fan itself acts as a flow separator by centrifuging small pieces of debris away from the engine core and into the bypass duct, where they can't do much damage.

Comment: Another factor making inlet screens win the cost-benefit analysis for large helicopters is the incredible amount of junk that their own downwash can throw around. -- As comedian Ron White says about hurricanes, "It ain't *that* the wind blows -- it's *what* the wind blows."  When a small helicopter lands, it will kick up leaves and so forth.  With a large helicopter, the whole branch is coming.

Comment: +1 for TomMcW's comment "and take the screen with it". Any "protective" thing you install can easily become a danger to what it was supposed to protect, if not very well engineered and installed. Cost-benefit analysis isn't just dollars-vs-danger, sometimes it's one danger relative to another.