# What exactly are these two cones on top of this Sikorsky S-61 helicopter?

Tags: helicopter, feature-identification

Haven't notice this thing on the Sikorsky, what is it?

[image]

Another picture from another angle:

[image]

Comment: These are engine inlet screens, to prevent FOD ingestion. See [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44946/what-are-these-engine-inlet-devices-used-for) question for a very similar device:

Comment: Thats what I thought but wasn't sure. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it or should I delete this post?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are engine inlet screens, to prevent [FOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_object_damage?wprov=sfla1) ingestion. See [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44946/what-are-these-engine-inlet-devices-used-for) question for a very similar device.

Comment: These seem to have an additional trick up their sleeves, in that they are not just *screens* but also *deflectors*.

Comment: yup, that's what initially caught my attention, that's a good idea so that the FOD doesn't stay fixed to the screen by the suction force.